# How to make Seaborn plot graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I want to make bar graph btw the Employment Status and the counts of the status . i want to plot from seaborn library and palette = "viridis" .

```
df_loan_2['EmploymentStatus'].value_counts()

Employed         67310
Full-time         7927
Self-employed     4538
Other             3806
Not employed       649
Retired            367
Part-time          256
Name: sum, dtype: int64
```

## In matplotlib code is this

```
df_loan_2['EmploymentStatus'].value_counts().plot(kind='barh',color='red')
plt.title('EmploymentStatus')
plt.xlabel('count')
plt.ylabel('status')
plt.fontsize = 12
plt.figsize=(12,12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like so with barplot:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.barplot(x=df_loan_2['EmploymentStatus'].value_counts().index, y=df_loan_2['EmploymentStatus'].value_counts())
```

Or you can do it with a countplot in seaborn in an easier way:

```
sns.countplot(x='EmploymentStatus', data=df_loan_2)
```